# I am unable to connect to Dynnamics 365 Business Central(on-premises) in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am not able to connect to dynamics 365 business central(on-premises) in powerbi.
I am getting this error :
"Dynamics 365 Business Central (on-premises): Request failed: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect to connect application directly ?

Comment: Yes, I can connect